# Does "Runas" in Windows Powershell simply not work without a GUI?

Tags: powershell

I am using AWS SSM to connect to Microsoft AD deployed within AWS, but it seems like managing anythign from the CLI is pretty difficult as the default `ssm` login user is `ssm-user`, and therefore I can't run any commands on the domain and see their output.

For example:

```
PS C:\> runas /userd:administrator@id.wrksp.mydomain.com "cmd.exe /c net users /domain"
Enter the password for administrator@id.wrksp.mydomain.com:
Attempting to start cmd.exe /c net users /domain as user "administrator@id.wrksp.mydomain.com" ...
PS C:\>
```

This doesn't work.

Connecting to the server via RDP doesn't work either because of a Micrsooft bug that causes black screen issues, as shown below:

[image]

Tried suggestions here as well in terms of editing registry settings, etc. Registry updated, but no luck. I mean this is a brand new image so I don't understand why this is still a problem.

Any thoughts on either getting an actual working GUI or being able to run these commands from within powershell?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you want to do here as I don't really work with AWS, but if you want to invoke commands in PowerShell on a remote server then I'd take a look at [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.1) or [`Enter-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enter-pssession?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: If you want a Command Window on a remote computer the easiest method is to use `psexec` which is part of PSTools, download from Microsoft. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools

Comment: Fyi: it's normal that explorer is unavailable on a GUI-less (core) server, this isn't a bug. The problem you're posting has nothing to do with a coding problem and is out of scope for SO as far as I can see.

Comment: As for `Does “Runas” in Windows Powershell simply not work without a GUI?`, it is used for any type of PowerShell session you want o start. The command you are using is not Powershell, it's for cmd.exe. That is not the way to run an executable from PowerShell. Running executables for PowerShell is a well-discussed, well-documented thing.

Comment: Why are you not using the AWS PowerShell module, thus avoiding the need fo cmd.exe at all?

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment...

You are running a cmd.exe line in PowerShell...

```
runas /userd:administrator@id.wrksp.mydomain.com "cmd.exe /c net users /domain"
```

... that does not make it a PowerShell thing. PowerShell offers the -RunAs switch/parameters for elevated/other user credentials.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.1

If you are doing cmd.exe stuff in the PowerShell consolehost, you must call it correctly. Which includes proper quoting, string termination, etc.

Also, if you are trying to do this against a remote host, what you are doing is not valid. You must have PowerShell Remoting properly enabled, establish a remote session, then call that session.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote?view=powershell-7.1

[https://devops-collective-inc.gitbook.io/secrets-of-powershell-remoting/remoting-basics#:~:text=Enabling%20Remoting%20%20%20%E2%80%8B%20%20%20Enable-PSRemoting,use%20PSSessionConfiguration%20cmdlets%20%201%20more%20rows%20](https://devops-collective-inc.gitbook.io/secrets-of-powershell-remoting/remoting-basics#:%7E:text=Enabling%20Remoting%20%20%20%E2%80%8B%20%20%20Enable-PSRemoting,use%20PSSessionConfiguration%20cmdlets%20%201%20more%20rows%20)

The way to run external command in Powershell is fully documented here:

> • PowerShell: Running Executables
>
> https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx

Example:

```
5. The Call Operator &

Why: Used to treat a string as a SINGLE command. Useful for dealing with spaces.

In PowerShell V2.0, if you are running 7z.exe (7-Zip.exe) or another command that starts with a number, you have to use the command invocation operator &.

The PowerShell V3.0 parser do it now smarter, in this case you don’t need the & anymore .

Details: Runs a command, script, or script block. The call operator, also known as the "invocation operator," lets you run commands that are stored in variables and represented by strings. Because the call operator does not parse the command, it cannot interpret command parameters

Example:

& 'C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe' "c:\videos\my home video.avi" /fullscreen
Things can get tricky when an external command has a lot of parameters or there are spaces in the arguments or paths!

With spaces you have to nest Quotation marks and the result it is not always clear! 

In this case it is better to separate everything like so:

$CMD = 'SuperApp.exe'
$arg1 = 'filename1'
$arg2 = '-someswitch'
$arg3 = 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt'
$arg4 = '-yetanotherswitch'
 
& $CMD $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4
 
# or same like that:
 
$AllArgs = @('filename1', '-someswitch', 'C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\some other file.txt', '-yetanotherswitch')
 
& 'SuperApp.exe' $AllArgs


7. Start-Process  (start/saps)
Technet Jump

Why: Starts a process and returns the .Net process object Jump if -PassThru is provided. It also allows you to control the environment in which the process is started (user profile, output redirection etc). You can also use the Verb parameter (right click on a file, that list of actions) so that you can, for example, play a wav file.

Details: Executes a program returning the process object of the application. Allows you to control the action on a file (verb mentioned above) and control the environment in which the app is run. You also have the ability to wait on the process to end. You can also subscribe to the processes Exited event.

Example:

#starts a process, waits for it to finish and then checks the exit code.
$p = Start-Process ping -ArgumentList "invalidhost" -wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru
$p.HasExited
$p.ExitCode



#to find available Verbs use the following code.

$startExe = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo -args PowerShell.exe

$startExe.verbs
```

Or your command:

```
# Start Powershell with a differnet use credential - showing the current user as an example
Start-Process powershell -Credential -Credential "$env:USERNAME@$env:USERDNSDOMAIN" -ArgumentList "-NoExit","-Command  &{ cmd.exe /c net users /domain }" -PassThru -Wait
```

You must also understand the following:

> about_Command_Precedence
>
> If you do not specify a path, PowerShell uses the following precedence
> order  when it runs commands for all items loaded in the current
> session:
>
> 1 - Alias
>
> 2 - Function
>
> 3 - Cmdlet
>
> 4 - External executable files (programs and non-PowerShell scripts)
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence?view=powershell-7

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your suggestion but wasn't able to produce any results. The command just hung. I'm basically connecting to a Windows AD server through AWS SSM and it lands me in a powershell. I'm trying to just run "net /domain" commands from the powershell prompt, but using the domain admin's account.

Comment: If you are landing on a Windows server and AWS is dropping you into PowerShell directly, nothing stops you from shelling into cmd.exe  to do what you want. Just type cmd in the PS consolehost to switch to the cmd.exe shell. Once done, just type exit. If you need to run elevated, then you can do that as well.

Comment: I run into the same issue as I do in Powershell, which is retrieving the output of the commands. It just sits at "Attempting to start xyz command..." and that's it. Even redirecting the output doesn't seem to generate any files. I suppose this is probably another issue, but nonetheless the response here was super helpful!

Comment: Hummm.. that is very odd. StdOut should give you your results. I no longer have an AWS instance to mess with, so, cannot repro what you are trying. Did you try and first elevate PS to admin then start cmd.exe, or just start cmd.exe elevated from PS, this way.   `start-process -FilePath cmd.exe -Verb RunAs`, you will get prompted for creds, unless you are already logged on as an admin. AWS notwithstanding, as for this `"Attempting to start xyz command..."`, this usually an indication of the resource not being found/reachable, or auth double-hop issues or the like.

Comment: Yep I've tried to elevate with `runas` in cmd, and tried the `-Verb RunAs` in PowerShell as well, but both result in the same "Attempting to start xyz" error, even if I just have it run `ipconfig > C:\results.txt` or some other folder. I may have to play around with this more in the RDP GUI